# Javascript drag from mouse position?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script which allows a user to drag a div around the screen on iOS, and as it is now, when you start to drag a div, it makes the dragable point the center. Is it possible to make this point wherever the user touches?

The code looks like this:

```
    xPos = drag.offsetWidth / 2;
    yPos = drag.offsetHeight / 2;
    drag.addEventListener("touchmove", function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).css({
            "left" : event.targetTouches[0].pageX - xPos + "px", 
            "top" : event.targetTouches[0].pageY - yPos + "px",
            "z-index" : "1000"
        });
        $("div").not(this).css("z-index", "1"); 
        $("div[id]").each(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            localStorage.setItem(id + "-z","1");
        });     
    });
```

Is there anyway I can make it so that the offset is however far away the user's finger is away from the box's edge?

---

I thought the following might work but it doesn't seem to, all it does is cause it to jitter:

```
$(this).css({
"left" : event.targetTouches[0].pageX - parseInt($(this).css("left"), 10) +  "px", 
"top" : event.targetTouches[0].pageY  - parseInt($(this).css("top"), 10) +  "px",
});
```

Comment: Modernizr  is a great, lightweight way to do all kinds of feature detection.

Comment: Can you post an example, @coder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. After testing, the following only produced the number of pixels from the left or top of the parent.

```
event.targetTouches[0].pageX - $(this).offset().left
```

The trick was to subtract that **FROM** `event.targetTouches[0].pageX`, which is the number of pixels that the finger is from the edge of the screen.

So, the completed code would look like this:

```
drag.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
    left = event.targetTouches[0].pageX - $(this).offset().left;
    top = event.targetTouches[0].pageY - $(this).offset().top;
});
drag.addEventListener("touchmove", function() {
    $(this).css({
        "left" : event.targetTouches[0].pageX - left + "px", 
        "top" :  event.targetTouches[0].pageY - top + "px",
    });
});
```